# Physically-based fracture simulation with opengl/c++

Tags: c++, opengl

I am trying to implement the ideas in this paper for modeling fracture:
http://graphics.berkeley.edu/papers/Obrien-GMA-1999-08/index.html

I am stuck at a point (essentially page 4...) and would really appreciate any help.  The part I am stuck on involves the deformation of tetrahedron (using FEM).

I have a single tetrahedron defined by four nodes (each node has a x, y, z position) in which I calculate the following matrices from:

- **u:** each column is a vector containing material coordinates (x, y, z,
  1) for each node  (so total 4 columns), a 4x4 matrix
- **B:** inverse(u), he calls this the basis matrix, a 4x4 matrix
- **P:** each column is a vector containing real world coordinates (x, y,
  z) for each node, I set P is initially equal to u since the object is
  not deformed at the rest state, a 3x4 matrix
- **V:** give some initial velocities for (x, y, z) in each node, so a 3x4
  matrix
- **delta:** basically an identity matrix, `{{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0,
  1}, {0, 0, 0}}`

I get `x(u) = P*B*u` and  `v(u) = V*B*u`, but not sure where to use these...

Also, I get `dx = P*B*delta`  and  `dv = V*B*delta`

I then get strain by Green's strain tensor, `epsilon = 1/2(dx+transpose(dx)) - Identity_3x3`

And then stress, `sigma = lambda*trace(epsilon)*Identity_3x3 + 2*mu*epsilon`

I get the elastic force by equation (24) on page 4 of the paper.  It's just a big summation.

I then using explicit integration to update real world coordinates P.  The idea is that the velocity update involves the force on the node of the tetrahedron and therefore affects the real-world coordinate position, making the object deform.

The problem, however, is that the force is incredibly small...something x 10^-19, etc.  So, c++ usually rounds to 0.  I've stepped through the calculations and can't figure out why.

I know I'm missing something here, just can't figure out what.  What update am I not doing correctly?

Comment: It sounds as though this might be a math problem as much as it is a programming problem.  If you don't find a suitable answer here, you could also try http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Why the OpenGL/C++ tags? Your question seems to be largely language/API agnostic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common reason why the force is small is that your Young's modulus (lambda) is too small. If you are using a scale of meters, a macro scale object might have 10^5 young's modlus and a .3 to .4 Poisson's ratio.

It sounds like what might be happening is that your tet is still in the rest configuration. In the presence of no deformation, the strain will be zero and so in-turn the stress and force will also be about zero. You can perturb the vertices in various ways and make sure your strain (epsilon) is being computed correctly.  One simple test is to scale by 2 about the centroid which should give you a positive strain.   If you scale by .5 about the centroid you will get a negative strain. If you translate the vertices uniformly you will get no change in strain (a common FEM invariant). If you rotate them you probably will get a change, but a co-rotational constitutive model wouldn't.

Note you might think that gravity would cause deformation, but unless one of the vertices is constrained, the uniform force on all vertices will cause a uniform translation which will not change the strain from being zero.

You definitely should not need to use arbitrary precision arithmetic for the examples in the paper. In fact, floats typically are sufficient for these types of simulation.

Comment: These are all great points.  I'm going to review my code again to double-check.  Also, I am indeed using floats :)

Answer (score 0):

I might be mistaken, but c++ doubles only go to 15 decimal places, (at least that's what my std::numeric_limits says). So you're way out of precision.

So you might end up needing a library for arbitrary precision arithmetics, e.g., http://gmplib.org/